# Net of a cuboid

Tags: geometry

[image: cuboid]

Which one is a valid net ?

---

My attempt :
The $1$ is wrong because one face has not opposite and the $3$ looks wrong, one face has not opposite. The $4$ is wrong too : two opposite faces are not isometric.

Comment: Figure 2 and 3 are both correct.

Comment: I agree with you about 1, 3 and 4. 2 looks good to me. Where does this come from? Is it an aptitude test for would-be packaging designers?

Comment: I see: it seems to me like quite a hard exercise in spatial imagination (except for 4 where the faces of the cuboid don't pair up properly). I think Seyed is right about 3 (and you and I were wrong).

Comment: Indeed, it was a difficult one